# Google map not displaying HTML (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps

Not sure why the google map cannot display

HTML Code

```
<div id="map" style="width:400px;height:600px;"></div>
<script>
    function initMap() {
        var location = { lat: 1.275699, lng: 103.845802 };
        var map = new goole.maps.Map(document.getElementByID("map"), {
            zoom: 5
            center: location})
        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({ position: myCenter });
            marker.setMap(map);
        });
    }
</script>

<script async defer
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCwXow-YSSaavXynAkBF1TkpAPKijAC-Qk&callback=initMap"></script>
```

I haven't added any CCS code for the map.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there are syntax errors in your code I have corrected them [ref](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/tutorial)

```html
<div id="map" style="width:400px;height:600px;"></div>
<script>
  var map;

  function initMap() {
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
      center: {
        lat: -34.397,
        lng: 150.644
      },
      zoom: 8
    });
  }
</script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCwXow-YSSaavXynAkBF1TkpAPKijAC-Qk&callback=initMap" async defer></script>
```